# Is there a domain search tool on the web that works well?

Tags: domains

I would like to search for all available domains ending with a particular word.  The best tool I've found for this so far is domainsbot, but it doesn't seem to work as it should (it will only give you the first 10 or so results for your criteria)

Does anyone know of a good tool on the web for this type of search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.eurodns.com/ then go to the "Advanced Search" tab. I like this site because the suffix list is very vast, and the prices are reasonable. You also have the option to only show domains that are available, so that can save some time too.

As for finding domains ending in a specific WORD, you may be better off with http://www.bustaname.com/word_maker. That's a really really nice one.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't get the first to return any results at all, but the second was very useful!

Comment: Same results: eurodns.com gave me results that were not avaialble. And it costs 3x as much as buying through BustaName.com (to GoDaddy).

Answer (score 0):

I find http://www.gandi.net/ to be easy to use. If you check 'All', then type in the word it'll show you all different domains you can get, along with their prices (for simple TLDs like .com, not your best place to shop, but still helpful).

You can also check if a full domain name is available.

Answer (score 0):

[Netcraft's SearchDNS service](http://searchdns.netcraft.com/?host) can search for sites matching a word or those that match the start or end with a specified string. It can also handle subdomain matches & wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

http://domai.nr/ is also cool to search for domain name.

It will also give you some alternative based on what you type. And the interface is pretty cool too.