# What are some good services for brainstorming domain name ideas?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a domain search tool on the web that works well?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29386/is-there-a-domain-search-tool-on-the-web-that-works-well)

I've run across a few of these but can't remember them right now (and I've probably missed a few good ones).

The idea is that you provide some input (a word(s)) and it comes up with synonyms, rhyming words, etc.

Ideally, I'd want to have some confidence that they aren't just registering all the domains I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

[Lean Domain Search](http://www.leandomainsearch.com/) is really fast and great for this kind of thing.